# Reversible Karhunen-Loeve Transform

Tags: transform, pca, image-compression

I have a problem with implementing RKLT. I've read through papers by Pengwei Hao and Qingyun Shi but i still have some questions. Has anybody seen an implementation of this transform?
I don't know how the permutation matrix should look like and how to obtain SERM factorization from the TERM factorization.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a C implementation od PLUS factorization by dr Pengwei Hao:

http://www.eecs.qmul.ac.uk/~phao/PLUS/plus.c